# How do I enable IPv6 with Nginx on Debian 10

Tags: nginx, debian-buster

I have a problem for a new install on debian 10 to use an IPv6 address on Nginx. The version of Nginx is 1.14.2. When I verify that Nginx supports IPv6, I see that it is not enabled. I use this command:

```
nginx -V
```

Previously I did an installation on Debian 9 where Nginx (v. 1.10.3) had IPv6 support enabled by default.

I fixed my problem on Debian 10 by compiling Nginx with the --with-ipv6 option. But I'm surprised it's no longer enabled by default. That's why I opened this post.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! Please don't edit your solution into your question. Instead, post an answer and accept it. Otherwise the question will stay as "unanswered" in the system and pop up again and again in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I continued my research and saw that between version 1.10.3 and version 1.14.2 Nginx had removed the flag --with-ipv6 to integrate by default the support of IPv6. Mystery solved.

Source: http://nginx.org/en/CHANGES

> Changes with nginx 1.11.5
>
> *) Change: the --with-ipv6 configure option was removed, now IPv6 support is configured automatically.